# Reference Request: Wild boar and a foolish son of a king who later became wise

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, devi

What's the source of this story? I don't remember the exact wordings - but I am somewhat familiar with certain lines of it

> - A rishi angered, cursed a king that his son would be born as a *murkha* (or fool).
> - After that cooldown, and sincere apologies from the king, he got into his senses and realized his deeds.
> - Since the bane couldn't be canceled, he later gave his boon to the son, eventually he'll become very wise in his life.
> - His son was born with a foolish characteristic and was mocked by all the people - takes an oath that he'd always speak truth, otherwise not.
> - Went into a forest one day and an injured wild boar comes across him. He takes it to his hut and the sound of the wild boar (*ain*, *ain*, etc) - was a beeja mantra for wisdom.
> - A hunter stumbles to him and asks, if he has seen a wild boar, his family and small children need food.
> - Struck in a contradiction, of speaking the truth (the boar will get killed), or stay in silence (the family and kids wouldn't get to eat anything).
> - The wise man speaks - "*Don't you know, the eyes that see cannot speak and the mouth that speaks cannot see?*"
> - The eyes might have seen the boar, but they cannot speak, mouth can speak, but it cannot see the boar.